# A method which call an external Api return an interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I use restsharp to consume an external API.
I have a class that extends the interface

```
public interface ICarInfo
{
    ICarDetails GetCarInfo(string car);
}

public interface ICarDetails
{
    string Color { get; set; }
    string MaxSpeed { get; set; }
    string Acceleration{ get; set; }

}
```

I create the class which extends this interface and implement this method using restsharp

```
public ICarDetails GetCarInfo(string car)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("/{car} ? access_key =xxxxxxxxx", Method.GET);
        var queryResult = client.Get<ICarDetails >(request).Data;
        return queryResult;
    }
```

Now i get an error in this line:

```
var queryResult = client.Get<ICarDetails >(request).Data;
```

> ICarDetails must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as a parameter T in the generic type or
>   method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concrete class is needed in order to be able to deserialize the request data.

So refactor the definitions accordingly

```
public interface ICarInfo {
    CarDetails GetCarInfo(string car);
}

public class CarDetails {
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string MaxSpeed { get; set; }
    public string Acceleration{ get; set; }
}
```

And the implementation

```
public CarDetails GetCarInfo(string car) {
    var client = new RestClient("http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("/{car} ? access_key =xxxxxxxxx", Method.GET);
    var queryResult = client.Get<CarDetails>(request).Data;
    return queryResult;
}
```

Even if you insist on keeping the `ICarDetails` interface, you will still need a concrete implementation for deserialization.

```
public interface ICarInfo {
    ICarDetails GetCarInfo(string car);
}

public interface ICarDetails {
    string Color { get; set; }
    string MaxSpeed { get; set; }
    string Acceleration{ get; set; }    
}

public class CarDetails : ICarDetails {
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string MaxSpeed { get; set; }
    public string Acceleration{ get; set; }
}
```

Again making sure the concrete class is used

```
public ICarDetails GetCarInfo(string car) {
    var client = new RestClient("http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("/{car} ? access_key =xxxxxxxxx", Method.GET);
    var queryResult = client.Get<CarDetails>(request).Data;
    return queryResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use interface in this section.
In this case, you want to cast the received value into an interface that is not possible. This is because the compiler need a type to be able create instance of it and then cast recived value into instance. It actually requires a class with the parameterless constructor. You should use concrete class instead of interface to solve the problem.